# How to make a Tkinter widget stick to window border after a widget removing operation?

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a column of buttons crated by `for` statement, I set the attribute so the last button can stick to the right border even if I resize the main window, I delete the last one by `destroy` method but the last of remains won't stick border if I resize the main window. How could I fix it to make it stick to the right boder? I've tried everything I can, but no effect.Many thanks.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

root = tk.Tk()
buttons = [None] * 7


def del_button():
    for i in range(5, 7):
        buttons[i].destroy()


for i in range(7):
    buttons[i] = ttk.Button(root, text=f"{i}")
    buttons[i].grid(column=i, row=0, sticky=tk.E)
    root.columnconfigure(i, weight=1)

button_del = ttk.Button(root, text='Delete', command=del_button)
button_del.grid(column=0, row=1)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Add `root.columnconfigure(i, weight=0)` after `buttons[i].destroy()`.

Comment: @acw1668 Excellent, it works! Problem solved, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @acw1668 said, adding `root.columnconfigure(i, weight=0)` after `buttons[i].destroy()` solves the problem. Many thanks to all the guys who posted suggestions.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

root = tk.Tk()
buttons = [None] * 7


def del_button():
    for i in range(5, 7):
        buttons[i].destroy()


for i in range(7):
    buttons[i] = ttk.Button(root, text=f"{i}")
    buttons[i].grid(column=i, row=0, sticky=tk.E)
    root.columnconfigure(i, weight=1)

button_del = ttk.Button(root, text='Delete', command=del_button)
button_del.grid(column=0, row=1)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

Implementing this  through pack() geometry manager is easy

**Note:** I have modified the loop for the button and used a frame for the delete button and frame for number buttons

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

root = tk.Tk()
buttons = [None] * 7


def del_button():
    for i in range(5, 7):
        buttons[i].destroy()

f1=tk.Frame(root)
for i in range(6,-1,-1):
    buttons[i] = ttk.Button(f1, text=f"{i}")
    buttons[i].pack(side=tk.RIGHT)
f2=tk.Frame(root)
button_del = ttk.Button(f2, text='Delete', command=del_button)
button_del.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
f1.pack(fill=tk.X,expand=True)
f2.pack(fill=tk.X,expand=True)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you! But could grid geometry manager achive this goal? All my code were using grid geometry manager...I heard that mixing geometry managers is a bad code style

Comment: @excper: actually, mixing geometry managers is a best practice. You should use the right tool for the job. Mixing the managers for widgets _with the same master_ is wrong, but mixing them in the app as a whole is encouraged.

Comment: @BryanOakley actually I haven't learnt pack() carefully, I will learn it, thank you.

Comment: @excper acc. to my exp it's easy compared to grid but u need to learn frames for that .All the best

Comment: `root.columnconfigure()` will get the job done, for grid